# Custom response from Volley

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

When i'm making a request and it fails, it shows the Toast with a full response error, I just want the "message" from it and not the whole JSON.

**I want to make the message only appear and not the whole JSON String.**

This is my **JSON** String:

```
{"status":false,"message":"message here"}
```

This is the **onResponse** function:

```
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response){
            try {
                JSONObject volleyResponse = new JSONObject(response);

                boolean success = volleyResponse.getBoolean("success");
                final String message = volleyResponse.getString("message");

                if(success){
                    messageText.setText("success");
                }
            } catch(JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(Authentication.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, that is not possible.

There are two main failure cases. One is if you have some sort of networking problem, in which case `onResponse()` is not called, and you do not have any JSON to work with.

The other, shown in your code above, is if you have a JSON parsing error. In that case, you cannot get the message, because the message is in the JSON, and you are unable to parse that JSON. What you are showing in the `Toast` is not valid JSON (as otherwise, you would not have gotten a `JSONException`).

In your exception handler, add:

```
Log.e("heyoooooo", "Exception parsing JSON", e);
```

Then, [look at the Java stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this) to see more details about the particular parsing error.

Comment: I should remove the "success" string and leave the message itself and display it to a TextView?

Comment: There isn't actually much of an error, it's more like a "authentication" problem, like invalid username, and password

Comment: @heyoooooo: Your two comments do not seem to be related to this question. Your question is about what is shown in the `Toast` ("it shows the Toast with a full response error, I just want the "message" from it and not the whole JSON"). You are showing the `Toast` in response to a `JSONException`, based on the code shown in your question.